# 'Cannot find declaration to go' CLion error

Tags: c++, makefile, cross-compiling, clion, jetbrains-ide

I've create project from Makefile. It's build success, but when I click on any method, or object, CLion displays an error:

> Cannot find declaration to go

I tried to delete `.idea` directory, and start 'Invalidate Caches', but this didn't work.

Comment: Does configuring of Makefile project finished well? There should be Build tool windows after you open the project first time. Or you can call Tools | Makefile | Reload Makefile project action. Probably CLion was not able to build project model well. In this case most of all IntelliJ feature will not work.